# Play Video file other than MP4

Tags: iphone, ios6, video-player

I want to play video files other than MP4 in my code
is there any way to do it?
Even if there was any would apple allow such app in the appstore

Thanks in advance
Regards
Nitesh

Answer (score 0):

from apple guide:

The video technologies in iOS support the playback of movie files with the .mov, .mp4, .m4v, and .3gp filename extensions and using the following compression standards:

H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
Numerous audio formats, including the ones listed in “Audio Technologies”

Comment: So do u have any idea how would it be possible to play an avi file?

Comment: You have to use a converter